# How to combine two tables to get results

Tags: sql

The following is my master table:

```
    tablename       columnname         size  order
    employee        name               25    1
    employee        sex                25    2
    employee        contactNumber      50    3
    employee        salary             25    4
    address         street             25    5
    address         country            25    6
```

And following is my child table:

```
    childid  userid  masterid  isactive  size   order
    1        1       1         Y         25     1
    2        1       2         Y         25     2
    3        1       3         N         0      0
    4        1       4         Y         50     3
```

I would like to get the table name columnname from master table and size,order form child table against userid when `isactive is Y` in child table.

Some time, if the value is not there for the particular user than get all the values like tablename, columnname, size, order `where isactive is`Y

I am really sorry to ask this but I am not good at SQL.

Regards.

Comment: how are the two tables connected with each other?

Comment: Did you try `UNION` operator ? Please add the errors you are facing along with the SQL command

Comment: there is no any relation between these two table.

Comment: The problem is not Java related. As JohnWoo commented, it would be good if you post how the tables are related.

Comment: `SELECT rcm.tablename, rcm.columnname, rcc.size, rcc.order from report_customise_master rcm
LEFT JOIN report_customise_child rcc ON rcm.id = rcc.masterid
WHERE rcm.isactive = 'Y' and rcc.isactive = 'Y'` i tried with this query it gives me correct result but if No record is there in child table for the particular user than i face problem to get results

Comment: @Learner how abount using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT rcm.tablename, rcm.columnname, rcc.size, rcc.order 
from report_customise_master rcm 
        INNER JOIN report_customise_child rcc 
            ON rcm.id = rcc.masterid 
WHERE rcm.isactive = 'Y' and rcc.isactive = 'Y'
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
..., COALESCE(rcc.size, rcm.size) as Size, 
     COALESCE(rcc.`Order`, rcc.`order`) as `Order`
```

Comment: thanks, John ,yes it gives the correct answer, but as i mentioned,this query is fine when the record exist in both the table and when report_customise_child has record for the particular user how to get them, also if the child table does not have value for the particular user than i have to take all the values from report_customise_master table hence i don't need to consider the child table at all. how to go about?

Comment: @Learner i think you mean this, ..., COALESCE(rcc.size, rcm.size) as Size, COALESCE(rcc.Order, rcc.order) as Order

Comment: Thanks, It helped to some extend but when the user id is not there in child table than i get no result but i should get results from master table.